# anchor tag with background image auto height come as zero

Tags: css, image, background

My css:

```
a.red, object, embed {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url(/bowties/red.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

My Html:

```
<a class="red"/>
```

What I want to do is have the image automatically sized right so I can use these as menu items. One on top of the next and so on. If I kept them in an image tag wrapped in an anchor then "height: auto;" works. I want to turn them into sprites which is why I am pulling it out, but I would like these to scale based on the size of the screen. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you use width and height values in %'s, the computed values will depend on the containing block for the `<a>` elements.  You need to post code otherwise your question so that people can provide specific answers.

Comment: I can work with any recommendation. If I need to wrap it in a div, I can do so. My primary concern is to NOT specify a pixel size. I want to the page to be completely dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding this is not possible.

I found a resource that simply had me add a relatively sized 'filler' image. A blank placeholder that caused the div to get a height and width, then be able to be re-sized on the container re-size. Slight bit of a hack, but worked.